# Dismounting the emulated sd card to be used as internal storage and use the physical sd card instead?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card

Any way to Dismount the emulated sd card to be used as internal storage and use the physical sd card instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was *surprised* when I recognized, that the 4 Gbyte storage of my Android 4.2 device is partitioned such stupid way (1 G for system, 1 G for internal storage and 2 G for "internal SD card"), it makes the whole device unexpandable. I assume, you have the same problem.

I'm not an Android Guru, so I did just a little trick: I've *swapped SD cards* in the configuration: I've edited `/system/etc/vold.fstab`, and swapped `sdcard0` and `sdcard1` in mount commands.

> dev_mount sdcard /storage/**sdcard1** emmc@fat /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.0 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.0/mmc_host 
>   dev_mount sdcard2 /storage/**sdcard0** auto /devices/platform/goldfish_mmc.1 /devices/platform/mtk-msdc.1/mmc_host

Now "internal SD card" is my real SD card, and the 2 Gbyte partition (was: "internal SD card") is not accessible for the most of the apps (except factory ones, which can handle two SD cards, and ones which can use specified path).

**Caution**: if you don't know how to do it, you're probably shouldn't do it. If you make mistake in configuration files, your device may not boot up. Always make backup, install recovery etc. Anyway, if your SD card configuration is wrong, it's not a fatal error, the only effect is that you'll have no SD card mounted. So be sure that all the tools needed (file manager, root manager, SSH server etc.) are installed on the internal storage.

Comment: well this partially solves it , i already foun this solution with a different approach , but the fact i want to know is that by doing this th internal emulated sd card remains as it is? so i will still have 1 G for system, 1 G for internal storage and 2 G for "internal SD card"? this is still a problem , what if i want to make the 1 gb of internal storage 3 gb merging it with theemulated sd partition?

Comment: Before: 1G:sys 1G:int 2G:int.SD 8G:Real.SD-can't-use
After: 1G:sys 1G:int 8G:Real.SD 2G:int.SD-can't-use

Comment: Well, I haven't tried to merge the partitions, I have lot of apps installed and still have 0.5 Gbyte internal storage. I have 8G SD card and I'm using factory app2sd method, I'm happy with it.

Comment: well thats the important part , i lack in internal storage

Comment: I think the answer is to combine the cards swap as stated in the above answer and use Link2SD to free the 1GB internal storage. Uninstall system apps, install them as user apps and think them to the SD. I am having problems with Link2SD alone so I will try the swap solution + Link2SD

Comment: @crramirez So did you try for swap solution + Link2SD? Link2SD requires a ext4 partition on sd card which does really work with the process described here. However I think only way to achieve this by making whole sd card partition ext4.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it. Just follow this tutorial:

http://blog.163.com/san_stars/blog/static/13683188020139404417393/

Step by step it only works if you make what he says. The application Root Internal 2 External is not in the store anymore so you need to look for the APK.

After that you can install Link2SD for a complete solution.

I recommend a complete wipe before using this method but is not neccesary

Regards

Comment: I will try this thanx and if it works i will mark your answer

Comment: I decided for this method because my tablet did not start anymore using the hard method in the other answer. This method works just be carefully in mount points and how many times you need to click Apply button.